# Call stack visualizer on exception

Tags: c#, exception

Is there a free call stack visualizer library?

I would like to present a full exception to the developer at runtime in an "easy to navigate" way outside Visual Studio. Possibly with a navigable tree containing all the frames.

Comment: create a exception handler (try/catch) then use the e.StackTrace instead of e.Message.

Comment: It doesn't have any visualizer.

Comment: So save it to a text/log file.  Send it to standard output and then view through output view window in VS.  Create a form and send it to a text box on the form.  there are lots of ways to view real time text from VS.

Comment: I don't need a text file/log. The whole point of the question: Is there a visualizer that takes the exception/call stack as argument and displays it in a nice navigable form?

Comment: The StackTrace is a text file with no formatting exception returns that you can display in any control that accepts string data.  Since there is no formatting, the output may not look pretty.

Comment: But I don't need just text.